# Trying to write a method to find the largest object from an array

Tags: java, arrays, max

Add a method:

```java
public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects)
```

to the `Data` class that returns the object with the largest measure.

This is what I have for code:

```java
public interface Measurable
{
    double getMeasure();
}
```

And the part I am having problems with:

```java
public class Data {
  //I am trying to come up with a method here

  public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects){
    double max = 0;
    for (Measurable obj : objects){
      if (obj.getMeasure() > max){
          obj =  max;
      }  
    }
   return max;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're no where assigning to the ``max`` variable in your ``max`` method.

Answer (score 2):

The `max` method should be like:

```java
public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects) {
   Measurable max = null;
   for (Measurable obj : objects) {
       if (max == null || obj.getMeasure() > max.getMeasure()) {
              max = obj;
       }  
    }
       return max;
}
```

If you're using Java 8, you could do:

```java
public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects) {
  return Arrays.stream(objects).max(Comparator.comparing(Measurable::getMeasure)).get();
}
```

Also, using

```java
for (Measurable obj : objects){
```

without `null` check is a recipe for `NullPointerException`.

**---- Edit ------**
Using the `max` method:

```java
Measurable max = Data.max(countries) // gives max measure containing object
System.out.println(max.getMeasure()) // prints the max measure value
```

Comment: My NetBeans doesn't like your command. It can't find the Arrays, Comparator, or Measure. @Adarsh

Comment: @Travis You need to import the relative classes. :) As of, `Measure` it's `Measurable`. It was a quick reference to help you. Updated the answer. BTW, the imports you need to add are: `import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;`

Comment: How do I test that method in the Main? I created:  Object tempObj2 = new Object(); then to test it I did    tempObj2 = Data.max(countries);   and it gave me   Max Country Size: measurabletester.Country@119d7047  when I printed the results.  @Adarsh

Answer (score 0):

One fairly idiomatic approach using the built-in Java libraries would be to use [`Stream.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Data {
    private static final Comparator<Measurable> MEASURABLE_COMPARATOR =
            Comparator.comparing(Measurable::getMeasure);

    public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects){
        return Arrays.stream(objects).max(MEASURABLE_COMPARATOR).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Initially set the `max` value to `object[0]` by `max =objects[0]` and then compare it with each iteration.

Refer the below code:

```
public class Data {
  public static Measurable max(Measurable[] objects){
    Measurable max = objects[0];  
    for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i] > max) {
            max = objects[i];
        }
    }
   return max;
  }
}
```